# How can I pass data to Python Flask that is NOT in a HTML form?

Tags: html, flask, request

I'm really new to web development and I'm trying to build my first project. 
I have a route with a HTML table that reflects a SQLite database table (just two columns: ID / Occupation name), where the user should be able to add, edit and delete rows of data. I'm struggling to code the edit/delete functions. 
[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbVLw.jpg)
As per the image above, when the user clicks to edit a row, I used javascript to change the "Occupation" column to a simple form with an input and a button. When "Save" is clicked, I want to send the INPUT and the ID columns to flask so I can update the sqlite table, but I couldn't figure out how since the ID is not actually on the form sending the request. 
I have considered adding an extra field on the form with the ID value, but I couldn't manage to make it work since I don't want it to be visible or editable in any way, besides it seems to be a "work around" instead of a proper way to solve it. 
Can you guys help me with this? I've been stuck on it for the last week or so and I really have no ideas at the moment. The flask, html and js are as follows. Thanks so much in advance! 
**Flask route**

```py
DATABASE = "teste.db"

@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Code to run a SQL command and change the specified ID
        new_value = request.form.get("new_value")
        #table_id = ??? -> can't get the ID value from the html

        conn = createConnection(DATABASE) 
        cur = conn.cursor()
        
        query = "UPDATE occupation SET occupation = ? WHERE id = ?"
        cur.execute(query, [new_value, table_id])
        cur.close()    
        conn.close()

        flash("Entry updated")
        return redirect("/data")

    else:
        conn = createConnection(DATABASE) 
        cur = conn.cursor()
        
        query = "SELECT * FROM occupation"
        occupations = cur.execute(query).fetchall()
        cur.close()    
        conn.close()

        return render_template("data.html", occupations=occupations)
```

**HTML**

```html
<table class="cd-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th class="absorbing-column">Occupation</th>
        <th colspan=3 class="table-actions">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tb-profissoes-body">
    {% for row in occupations %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
        <td class="cd-edit pointer"><img src="/static/icons/edit.svg"></></td>
        <td class="cd-delete pointer"><img src="/static/icons/delete.svg"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```js
const edit_buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".cd-edit");
edit_buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // gets the row data based on which edit icon was clicked
        let row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        let data = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        
        // gets the data we want to change in the sqlite database
        let node = data[1];
        let index = data[0].innerText;
        let current_value = node.innerText;

        // Changes the node to be a FORM instead of plain text
        node.innerText = "";
        const form = document.createElement("form");
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        const button = document.createElement("button");

        form.classList.add("cd-edit-form");
        form.action = "/data";
        form.method = "post";
        input.classList.add("cd-edit-input");
        input.value = current_value;
        input.name = "new_value"
        input.autocomplete = "off";

        button.classList.add("cd-edit-button", "pointer");
        button.innerText = "Save";

        form.append(input);
        form.append(button);
        node.append(form);
        input.focus();
    })
})
```

Comment: Where does the ID value come from? It is static in the html example code but it has to be based on some variable in Flask in your real code (otherwise it wouldn't take different values as seen in the table image). Can you post your Flask code as well?

Comment: @Snoeren01 thanks for the reply! Actually when the route receives a GET request, it runs a SQL code to query the database and return the data to generate the table dynamically with jinja. When the user clicks the "edit" icon on the table, I've used Javascript to replace the column with a form, so that the user can change the value of that row. I have updated the HTML and included both Flask and Javascript. Thank you once again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't come up with an idea neither. Maybe you can modify your title to 'How to pass data from javascript-enhanced form to Flask?' to attract some more specific attention. I would love to see a solution as well. Passing variables can be really tricky.